# filter specific attribute from a file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have an input.txt file has following text. I have to filter the "".

```
- <ci>
  <id>a573f0d014c18a5811793aedb5aad3</id> 
  <viewName>Windows</viewName> 
  </ci>
- <ci>
  <id>7ad9088802ef62d75a15c9d4799fe8</id> 
  <viewName>Network</viewName>
  </ci>
- <ci>
  <id>abbbeeb60c4074bbc8483f321e0b43</id> 
  <viewName>Unix</viewName> 
  </ci>
```

Output should be like this:

```
a573f0d014c18a5811793aedb5aad3
7ad9088802ef62d75a15c9d4799fe8
abbbeeb60c4074bbc8483f321e0b43
```

Answer (score 0):

With gnu grep you can use a positive lookahead and a positive lookbehind:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=<id>).*(?=</id>)' file
a573f0d014c18a5811793aedb5aad3
7ad9088802ef62d75a15c9d4799fe8
abbbeeb60c4074bbc8483f321e0b43
```

Answer (score 0):

another `grep` alternative based on data pattern

```
 grep -o '[a-f0-9]\{30\}'
```

Comment: Yes, it retrieved all the ID's but at the end of each id's two characters is missing. Can you please correct that as well ?

Comment: Did I count wrong? Change 30 to the actual number of chars.

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lane 'print $1 if /^\s*<id>(\S+)<\/id>/' file
```

The /regex/ captures the information between < id > and < /id > into variable $1

These command-line options are used:

- `n` loop around every line of the input file, put the line in the $_ variable, do not automatically print every line
- `l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `a` autosplit mode – perl will automatically split input lines on whitespace into the @F array
- `e` : execute the perl code